# What features will be removed from Chromium?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

From what I understand, the Chromium web browser will ditch a lot of Google's code, but I don't understand what features will be purged. The [announcement](https://lists.webkit.org/pipermail/webkit-dev/2013-April/024388.html) is too technical for me; is there a list of features to be removed from an end-user perspective?

**Note:** My main concerns are the ability to sync with Google accounts and installing extensions from the Chrome Web Store.

Comment: Actually, it is the opposite way around.  Chrome and chromium will stop using webkit, so the webkit engine can dump all the chrome/chromium specific code.  Chrome/chromium will use the new Blink engine by Google, and should not have any functional difference to now.

Comment: @Paul I don't know why you commented, you should have posted it as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chromium isn't ditching Google's code. Both Chromium and Chrome are ditching WebKit, which is its current rendering engine (and which is not even remotely a Google product), for a custom fork called Blink. The announcement you saw was from a Webkit developer working for Apple, who has nothing whatsoever to do with Google or Chromium.

Comment: The news website I found it on said it was about Chromium... Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Google is not ditching WebKit per say.  They are indeed forking the project but only because of all the stuff being added to Webkit that Google didn't need.  They are still going to backport the rendering portion of Webkit into Blink ( likely submit their own changes to Webkit ).

Answer (score 1):

Google has [announced](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/04/blink-rendering-engine-for-chromium.html) that it's going to fork WebKit into [Blink](http://www.chromium.org/blink), a new rendering engine for Chrome. This is their claim from the announcement:

> In the short term, Blink will bring little change for web developers.
>   The bulk of the initial work will focus on internal architectural
>   improvements and a simplification of the codebase. For example, we
>   anticipate that we’ll be able to remove 7 build systems and delete
>   more than 7,000 files—comprising more than 4.5 million lines—right off
>   the bat. Over the long term a healthier codebase leads to more
>   stability and fewer bugs.